# Windows Azure appsettings and MVC 6 appsettings

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

In MVC 5 I could override my web.config appsettings with the appsettings in the Windows Azure portal. This doesn't seem to work anymore. What do the Azure appsettings translate to now? Are they still useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your own settings to the appsettings.json file. Just like MVC 5 and Web.config.

Here's a good read:

http://developer.telerik.com/featured/taking-control-of-configuration-in-mvc6/

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that, of how do these settings correspond with Azure appsettings.

Comment: If you read the article i linked, you can see how to override the settings in appsettings from Azure. Is that not your question?